# Applying for Greece tourist visa (Schengen) from a non residence country while on a tourist visa

Tags: visas, schengen, greece, uae, tourist-visas

This might get a little confusing but bear with me.

- Country of citizenship: India
- Country of residence: Canada (work
  permit)
- Countries I am about to visit: U.A.E. and the Greece

The decision to visit Greece was recent and so I do not have enough time between now and when I leave Canada to apply for my Greece tourist visa.

Since I am going to be spending about 3 weeks in the U.A.E. I was hoping to get my Greece tourist visa once there.

[Then I came across this visa information page](http://www.vfsglobal.com/Greece/uae/allaboutyourvisas.html):

> Only UAE nationals and nationals of third countries that are legal residents in UAE can apply for a visa at the Greece Visa Application Centre in Abu Dhabi and Dubai

I am not a U.A.E. national and only a tourist in U.A.E.

Would it be possible for me to get a Greece tourist visa while in U.A.E. ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can not apply for a Schengen visa while you are on a tourist visa in UAE, only nationals of UAE or legal residents can apply. This also applies for all Schengen visas in any country while you are a tourist.

Please note, legal residents means people on immigrant or work visas, this does not include tourist visas.

Comment: +1 I think that's the correct interpretation but the sentence was already quoted in the question so it doesn't help much by itself…

Comment: @Relaxed thanks! I thought it is a different one, I did not read the question carefully :)